# Get data from json array mysql into cells

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-insert

So I get such an array coming in my procedure

`{"4":false,"5":true,"6":false,"sch":"28"}`

Previously I used `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT( DATAA, '$.sch'))` to get the `sch` value from an array and put it in a cell, but now the task has changed and I need to get such records in the tables after the INSERT procedure

```
MARKS_ID |  SCHEDULE_ID | STUDENT_ID | MARKS_BOOL | MARKS_DATE
-------: | -----------: | ---------: | ---------: | --------:
       1 |           28 |          4 |      false |  CURTIME()
       2 |           28 |          5 |       true |  CURTIME()
       3 |           28 |          6 |      false |  CURTIME()
```

- MARKS_ID, SCHEDULE_ID, STUDENT_ID = INT
- MARKS_BOOL = BOOLEAN
- MARKS_DATE = DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()` for this. The idea is to extract the keys of the object using `json_keys()`, and to unnest them as rows using `json_table()`. Then, you can filter out unwanted key `sch`, and extract each corresponding value in the `select` clause:

```
set @js = '{"4":false,"5":true,"6":false,"sch":"28"}';

select 
    marks_id,
    json_unquote(json_extract(@js, '$.sch')) schedule_id,
    0 + student_id student_id,
    json_unquote(json_extract(@js, concat('$."', student_id, '"'))) = 'true' marks_bool
from json_table(
    json_keys(@js), 
    '$[*]' 
    columns (
        marks_id for ordinality,
        student_id varchar(10) path '$'
    )
) x
where student_id <> 'sch'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2d5ff67e86170da567b5f9cd5499425)**:

```
marks_id | schedule_id | student_id | marks_bool
-------: | ----------: | ---------: | ---------:
       1 |          28 |          4 |          0
       2 |          28 |          5 |          1
       3 |          28 |          6 |          0
```

---

You can easily turn this to an `insert` query:

```
insert into mytable(marks_id, schedule_id, student_id, marks_bool, marks_date)
select 
    marks_id,
    json_unquote(json_extract(@js, '$.sch')),
    student_id,
    json_unquote(json_extract(@js, concat('$."', student_id, '"'))) = 'true',
    now()
from json_table(
    json_keys(@js), 
    '$[*]' 
    columns (
        marks_id for ordinality,
        student_id varchar(10) path '$'
    )
) x
where student_id <> 'sch'
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0225a97a3b5976261d2aef4cdbf9313)**

Comment: But I need to insert data from the array to a table. Not select.

Comment: Do you specify schedule_id manually? I've tried to use `JSON_EXTRACT( @js, '$.sch');` but then i don't get any data on select =( You can check this out. [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6881922819602e5e19c8f9c7afb2ccf8)

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko: there are a few errors in your fiddle, [fixed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7975c2188027d7bb08f8fa0d8d3815f). But you are right, I misunderstood that part of your requirement. I modified my answer accordingly (there is no no need to use a temporary variable).